# Does using having reCAPTCHA V3 as App Check's attestation provider prevent fake signups?

Tags: firebase, forms, recaptcha-v3, firebase-app-check

My Vuejs3 web app uses Firebase and we just implemented App Check, using reCAPTCHA V3 as App Check's attestation provider.

Am I correct that reCAPTCHA V3 still needs to be distinctly implemented on a signup form (i.e., having reCAPTCHA V3 as the attestation provider does not in and of itself prevent, for example, a bot from signing up for 10,000 new accounts via the signup form)?

If so, anything to look out for when [adding reCAPTCHA](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) V3 to a Vuejs3 form in this scenario, or is it straightforward?

*As for what users experience, the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/web/recaptcha-provider) is clear that reCAPTCHA v3 is invisible to users and does not require users to solve a challenge at any time.*

Thanks for any help!